# Page renders faster than fetching the data and displaying it

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

How do i display data that i am grabbing using a fetch call and then setting it into an array and displaying in the Dom if it meets the conditions. Currently i am rendering the page faster than i am fetching the data and doing stuff with it.

thanks in advance

```
function Profile() {
  let myReceipe = [];
  const [isPopUp, setPopUp] = useState(false);

  ReceipeService.getReceipes().then(data => {
    myReceipe = data;
  })

  const popUpHandler = () => {
    setPopUp(!isPopUp);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className='profile'>
        <ProfileHeader/>
        <div className='createdposts'>
        {myReceipe.length !== 0 ? 
          <Post popUpHandler={popUpHandler} myReceipe={myReceipe}/>
          :
          null
        }
        </div> 
      </div>
      {isPopUp === true ? 
      <Magnify popUpHandler={popUpHandler}/>
      : 
      null
      }
  </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems in your code:

- You are not using the `useEffect` hook to make the HTTP request
- `myReceipe` should be in the state of your component

Data will always be loaded after your component has rendered.

The way you are fetching the data is not the correct way to do it. React has [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook that is built exactly for this purpose.
Fetching data from the server is a side-effect and all the side effects belong inside the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook. So, move the code that makes the HTTP request inside the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.

Also make sure that `myReceipe` is the local state of your component

```
const [myReceipe, setMyReceipe] = useState([]);
```

and when the data from the server is available, update the state to trigger a re-render so that you can show the data to the user.

```
useEffect(() => {
  ReceipeService.getReceipes()
    .then(data => {
       setMyReceipe(data);
    });
}, []);
```

While the data is not available, show some kind of loading spinner to the user to indicate to the user that data is loading.

Comment: you should make sure compoent is still mounted before you set ``` setRecipes(data);``` , just sue a variable ``` isMounted=true;``` then in the use effect return function ```isMounted=false```  and you check for isMounted before you setRecipes

Comment: @سعيد good point but i want to keep the code example as simple as possible to avoid confusing the OP about the problem that OP might or might not face.

Answer (score 0):

just use a state variable myReceipe then when myReceipe is set the Component will re render nthen call ReceipeService.getReceipes() in useEffect :

```
  let myReceipe = [];
  const [isPopUp, setPopUp] = useState(false);
  const [myReceipe , setmyReceipe ] = useState([]);
  useEffect(
  ()=>{
     let isMounted=true;
      ReceipeService.getReceipes().then(data => {
        // isMounted && insures the component is still mounted
        // or else this might through an error if the component has unmounted but the api call responded  because you cant just update staet of un unmounted Component 
        isMounted && setmyReceipe(data);
      })
        return ()=>{isMounted  = false }
  },[])
  

  const popUpHandler = () => {
    setPopUp(!isPopUp);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className='profile'>
        <ProfileHeader/>
        <div className='createdposts'>
        {myReceipe.length !== 0 ? 
          <Post popUpHandler={popUpHandler} myReceipe={myReceipe}/>
          :
          null
        }
        </div> 
      </div>
      {isPopUp === true ? 
      <Magnify popUpHandler={popUpHandler}/>
      : 
      null
      }
  </>
  )
}
```